# RF Cavity resonance based on E field

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, high-voltage, magnetics, high-frequency

Is it true that the resonant frequency of a pillbox type RF cavity is dependent on the E field and the cavity's geometry size, because for each frequency there is only one size/radius corresponding to where the E field vanishes at the cavity wall?

Would it be fair to say that if I had a RF cavity to which I supplied a variable frequency excitation power source and then  short circuited the RF cavity middle gap with a variable capacitor then I could have a continuum of resonant frequencies within the same cavity size just by adjusting the capacitor?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it true that the resonant frequency of a pillbox type RF cavity is dependent on the E field and the cavity's geometry size, because

No, since the E-field is a result of the excitation and the geometry, it can't be a cause for the resonant frequency.

The E-field changes – otherwise, you wouldn't have a electromagnetic propagation/Mawell's equations would have a 0 wherever a \$dt\$ was involved.

> Would it be fair to say that if I had a RF cavity to which I supplied a variable frequency excitation power source and then short circuited the RF cavity middle gap with a variable capacitor then I could have a continuum of resonant frequencies within the same cavity size just by adjusting the capacitor?

You can't "short" something with a capacitor, because a capacitor is not a short (it always introduces a phase shift).

Of course, you can detune *anything* by adding capacity, so the answer to this question is "yes".

However, you'll find it quite difficult to build a good variable capacitor that you can use "within" a cavity. You can't place it far away – this is RF, after all, so your transmission line(s) from cavity "capacitor feed point" to capacitor are important – and their electrical length is relative to wavelength, so this will have very surprising (non-monotonic) behaviour if you try to vary things over a significant frequency range.

Comment: Well I misspoke I was thinking that the resonant frequency for a given cavity is at the frequency where the E field exactly fills up the cavity? But imagine I had a cavity where the cavity is not pumped by particle bunches but instead magnetically (long story just assume) and the middle gap where the beam is is instead short circuited or has a variable capacitor there. Now in the case the middle is short circuited , would the cavity then have a resonant frequency or would it then be capable of operating within a wide frequency range ?

Comment: "The E filed exactly fills up the cavity": um, the E-field is a vectorial field that's defined at every point, this sentence makes no sense: of course it fills up the cavity. It fills up all the universe. I answered the rest of your comment already in my answer.